# DataTables warning: table - Invalid JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I know this must be one of the most popular questions. I can't see what's wrong with my data though. This is my php:

```
  $sql = "SELECT eventid, event_type, date_display, date_from, date_to, location, done FROM events LIMIT 0, 30";

  $get_result = mysql_query($sql);

$arr = Array();
 while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_result))
  {

              $arr['data'][] = $res;

  }

  echo json_encode($arr);
```

My JQuery:

```
function do_search()
{
 var search_term=$("#search_term").val();
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'get_results.php',
  data:{
   search:"search",
   search_term:search_term
  },
  success:function(response)
  {
     console.log(JSON.parse(response))

              $('#events').DataTable({
                ajax: JSON.parse(response),
                columns: [
                  { data: 'eventid' },
                  { data: 'event_type' },
                  { data: 'date_display' },
                  { data: 'date_from' },
                  { data: 'date_to' },
                  { data: 'location' },
                  { data: 'done' },
              ],
                "lengthMenu": [ [-1, 10, 25, 50, 100], ["All", 10, 25, 50, 100] ]
              });


  }
 });
```

And my HTML:

```
<table id="events" class="display" style="width:100%">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>From</th>
                  <th>To</th>
                  <th>Location</th>
                  <th>To do</th>

              </tr>
          </thead>

      </table>
```

This is the data I get in the console:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "eventid": "1",
            "event_type": "Senate meeting",
            "date_display": "61-60",
            "date_from": "61",
            "date_to": "60",
            "location": "Unknown",
            "done": "y"
        },
        {
            "eventid": "2",
            "event_type": "Legal hearing",
            "date_display": "73-70",
            "date_from": "73",
            "date_to": "70",
            "location": "Unknown",
            "done": ""
        },
[etc...]
    ]
}
```

As far as I can see I'm following the [data expected by DataTable](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)s. What am I missing?

I am getting seven fields for each record, and the table has seven fields indeed, also mapped in the JQuery code.

Comment: Why are you using the obsolete `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued in PHP 5.5 (2013) and removed entirely in PHP 7 (2015). No apps should still be using it. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` (both released in the 2000s!) as soon as possible, and learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Also, if you are running `mysql_` queries successfully, it shows you are running an unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @ADyson Unofrtunately it's not up to me, I'm on the server provided by my university and I agree, PHP is at a very obsolete state :( . I cannot upgrade it myself.

Comment: Can please the nice person who left a negative vote explain the rationale behind it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example at the link you posted here: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html, the `ajax` option in the datatables config is used to provide the URL of the file/script which returns the JSON data, so that datatables can initiate an AJAX request to fetch it.

Whereas what you've done is make your own AJAX request, and then pass the response to datatables. If you're going to do that, you should provide it to datatables via the `data` option instead. Your scenario, as coded now, is actually closer to this example: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

e.g.

```
$('#events').DataTable({
  data: JSON.parse(response),
```

P.S. For a more complete discussion how to configure DataTables to use an AJAX request as a data source directly, see https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Comment: Thank you. That's what I already tried. If I put `data` then the dable just shows a 'No data available in table' message, with no errors in the console.

Comment: ...and putting `ajax: 'get_results.php',`, again, gives me an `invalid data` worning.

Comment: OK, migrating to `mysqli` and then using `ajax` pointing to my `php` file did the trick, so I suppose the answer to my issue is a mix of your answer and @ADyson's one.